# SAHI capture screenshot on assert failure

Tags: javascript, sahi

Were running SAHI automated testing on our web site. Were looking into upgrading to SAHI pro so we can use the `_takeSnapShot` method.

We have thousands of `assert`s scattered all over our scripts. What we want is some kind of global way so that if an assert fails the system will fire `_takeSnapShot` and then continue.

We've tried a JavaScript `try{} catch{}` but SAHI doesn't actually throw an exception, it just logs the failure and continues.

We've also tried attaching an `_setRecovery` function as documented here http://sahi.co.in/w/_setrecovery-recovering-from-a-scenario-without-try-catch. But this doesn't fire!

Anyone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from http://sahi.co.in/w/sahi-call-back-functions

```
function onScriptError($e){
    _focusWindow();
    _takeScreenShot();  
} 
onScriptFailure = onScriptError;
_navigateTo("http://sahi.co.in/demo/training/"); 
_setValue(_textbox("user"), "test"); 
_setValue(_password("password"), "secret"); 
_click(_submit("Login"));
```